# Seeing "undefined" printed when iterating an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am iterating a JavaScript array object. I have written a function which iterates the array element. it works but above the result there is written 'undefined'. I don't want to see this, it would be great help to know how to solve this undefine word thing.

```js
var userlist = [{
    "username": "Tom",
    "Current_latitude": 23.752805,
    "Current_longitude": 90.375433,
    "radius": 500
  },

  {
    "username": "Jane",
    "Current_latitude": 23.752805,
    "Current_longitude": 90.375433,
    "radius": 400
  },

  {
    "username": "Dave",
    "Current_latitude": 23.765138,
    "Current_longitude": 90.362601,
    "radius": 450
  }, {
    "username": "Sarah",
    "Current_latitude": 23.792452,
    "Current_longitude": 90.416696,
    "radius": 600
  },

  {
    "username": "John",
    "Current_latitude": 23.863064,
    "Current_longitude": 90.400126,
    "radius": 640
  }
];


var x = Tom(userlist);

function Tom(user) {
  var text;
  for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
    text += "<li>" + user[i].username + "</li>";
  };
  //text+="</ul>"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=userlist[0].username+" "+userlist[0].Current_latitude +  " " + userlist[0].Current_latitude+"" + userlist[0].Current_longitude+" "+ userlist[0].radius;
```

```html
<p>How to create A javaScript Object Array.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to initialize your valiable `text` to an empty string, like this:

```
var text = "";
```

Uninitialized variables in JavaScript default to the special value [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), which is found as text in the concatenation.

As noted in the comments, there's an in issue in your HTML too: `<li>` tags should only appear inside a containing `<ul>`, `<ol>` or `<menu>` tag.
You may consider changing your `<li>`...`</li>` to something like `<div>`...`</div>` or wrapping the text concatendated text with `<ul>`...`</ul>`.

Comment: Given that the OP generates invalid HTML it would be better to initialize the variable to `<ul>` instead and uncomment the line that adds the end tag.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you haven't initialised your variable:

```
var text;  //text is undefined at this point
for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) 
{
    //the first iteration of the loop will append to "undefined"
    text+="<li>"+ user[i].username+"</li>";
};
```

Simply give it an initial value:

```
var text = '';
for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) 
{
    text+="<li>"+ user[i].username+"</li>";
};
```

As noted by Juhana, however, this isn't generating valid markup.  You can uncomment your closing tag, and initialise `text` to `<ul>` instead:

```
var text = '<ul>';
for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) 
{
    text+="<li>"+ user[i].username+"</li>";
};
text += "</ul>";
```